# Differential equation: finding a second solution that satisfies a 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+\frac{1}{x} y'-4y=0$$

If $y_{1}$ is a solution of the above equation and $y_{2}=y_{1}\ln(x)-w(x)$ is another solution, find a second order differential equation satisfied by w.

Should I differentiate $y_{2}$ twice, replace it in the equation and find $w(x)$ or is there another way?

Comment: Yep, you should go ahead and do that. It shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I get $$\frac{2y_{1}'}{x}+y_{1}''ln(x)-w''(x)+\frac{y_{1}'ln(x)}{x}-\frac{w'(x)}{x}-4y_{1}ln(x)+4w(x)=0$$

Do I set by identity, $-w''(x)+4w(x)=0$, forget the rest of the equation, solve and get $w=c_{1}e^{2x}+c_{2}e^{-2x}$ which is a solution of the second order differential equation $-y''+4y=0$?

Comment: You should group together terms that will be zero by virtue of $y_1$ being a solution to the original ODE. In this case they are all the terms involving $\ln(x)$. You are left with a second order *inhomogeneous* ODE for $w$.

Comment: Never mind my comment then, since I get a second order inhomogeneous ODE for w, the problem is done right? I can just say that w is a solution to that ODE?

Comment: That seems to be all the question in the OP is asking for, yes.